TS throwing errors in an no error prune part of code
for the following snippet of code, ts complains that "object is possibly null" with a red underline just below "rawMQTTTopicsResults[topic].timestamp < staleTimestamp.toString()"
for (const topic of Object.keys(rawMQTTTopicsResults)) {
    let stale: boolean = true
    if (rawMQTTTopicsResults[topic] && rawMQTTTopicsResults[topic].timestamp !== null){
      stale = rawMQTTTopicsResults[topic].timestamp < staleTimestamp.toString()
    }
    resultsWithStale[topic] = {
      ...rawMQTTTopicsResults[topic],
      stale: stale
    };
  }

and here is the type for "rawMQTTTopicsResults"
const rawMQTTTopicsResults: Record<string, {
    timestamp: string | null;
    value: string | number | boolean | null;
}>

it is worth noting that my vs-code compiler does not indicate this error, it only appears when building.
How is this even possible after the if condition check?

Looks like ts can't narrow the type as written. Try this instead:
for (const topic of Object.keys(rawMQTTTopicsResults)) {
    let stale: boolean = true
    let resultValue = rawMQTTTopicsResults[topic]

    if (resultValue && resultValue.timestamp !== null) {
      stale = resultValue.timestamp < staleTimestamp.toString()
    }

    resultsWithStale[topic] = {
      ...resultValue,
      stale: stale
    };
  }

